# CSS is not working in Outlook though its working in other mail clients

Tags: css, outlook, e-commerce, magento2, html-email

We have some email templates based on HTML for our website and we have changed some of the portions in the header. The email looks great and working as expected in the Gmail but when we look the same email template in Outlook app, there are some issues that the outlook is not taking the CSS which we had written. Below are the CSS properties or methods we have tried but its not working in Outlook though its working in other mail clients

```
float
flex
```

Below is the html code we are having for the email template:

```
<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner" align="center">
            <table class="main" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="header">
            <div style="float:left;">
                        <a class="logo" href="{{store url=""}}">
                            <img
                                {{if logo_width}}
                                    width="{{var logo_width}}"
                                {{else}}
                                    width="180"
                                {{/if}}

                                {{if logo_height}}
                                    height="{{var logo_height}}"
                                {{/if}}

                                src="{{var logo_url}}"
                                alt="{{var logo_alt}}"
                                border="0"
                            />
                        </a>
            </div>
            <div class="header-content" style="float:right;">Address Line 1<br/>
            Line 2
            </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

We need to move the div which is having the class `header-content` to the right side in the header but its not working in outlook app though its working in gmail.

Please guide.

Comment: `flex`, `float`, do not work in Outlook 200--2016. `div` are not really recognized as expected. I would follow what @Akshit Aggarwal mentions below.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations when it's comes to work on mailer, as all email clients doesn't support each css property. I am adding a working code snippet which will work in most of the email clients(Gmail, outlook etc).

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table style="max-width: 600px;width: 100%;margin: 0px auto;">
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Left</td>
        <td align="right">Right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Akshit. I will try your solution and update you